# Exclude magit autosaves from git log --all?

Tags: magit, git

I like the idea of `(magit-wip-after-save-mode)` but it makes `git log --all` (or `la` in Magit) very cluttered. Is there a simple way to exclude autosaves from all the autosave "branches"?

On the command-line, I can `$ git log --all --not 'refs/wip/wtree/refs/heads/master'` but that just excludes the autosaves that happened on the master branch, not autosaves on other branches (and replacing `master` with `*` doesn't dwim – I'd rather not have to specify all feature branches explicitly :-/).

Comment: Does `lb` do what you want?

Comment: Wow. That did it. Thanks! (If you add it as an answer, I'll ✔️ it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list just local and remote branches using <kbd>l b</kbd>.